# Recursive spaceship operator

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

I have written this simple code but it does not compile because the comparison is implicit deleted.

```
struct Tree {
    std::vector<Tree> child;

    friend auto operator<=>(const Tree &a, const Tree &b) = default;
}
int main(){
    Tree t;
    std::cout<<(t<t)<<std::endl;
}
```

Can anybody explain to me how to fix the problem or at least why it does not work?

Edit: compiled with "g++ -std=gnu++2a main.cpp"
Edit2:
Here is the error part of the output (it is followed by many, many lines of candidates):

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:31:25: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr auto operator<=>(const Tree&, const Tree&)'
   31 |     std::cout << (tmp < tmp) << std::endl;
      |                         ^~~
main.cpp:12:17: note: 'constexpr auto operator<=>(const Tree&, const Tree&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   12 |     friend auto operator<=>(const Tree &a, const Tree &b) = default;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:12:17: error: no match for 'operator<=>' (operand types are 'std::vector<Tree>' and 'std::vector<Tree>')
```

Comment: I can guess that this has to do with `Tree` being incomplete when used in `vector`.

Comment: Well gerum sais the comparison t<t is implicitly deleted. I wonder what happens if you would set this up to use two Tree instances instead of one ? t<t is always false, that is null.. that is the same as the default returned by this operator. So t<t is optimized away by the compiler ? What version of c++ is used..

Comment: @Goodies, `= default` is for generating a default definition of the operator. That definition exists regardless of the values you pass in—it's based on types.

Comment: I think the test in main() is just too short. There is an instance t, but it has an *empty* vector<Tree> child. I leave this to the cpp experts, but I feel it is logical this code is optimized away. There is no real "comparison" so the compiler will substitute false ?.

Comment: Seems like the same problem that you would get by putting a struct in itself. How can the compiler know how to compare it when it looks at one of the members and that in turn requires it to figure out if it can compare itself, and that in turn requires it to figure out if it can compare itself and so on...

Comment: Please provide the errors and the statement/flags you are using for compilation.

Comment: @Goodies Yes it likely will be optimized away, but according to the as if rule, that should not change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot usually define a recursive function with a deduced return type. In order to deduce it, you need to already know it, so this is a no go.

Replacing `auto` with an explicit return type `std::weak_ordering` [fixes the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/nMvhfr19Y).

Comment: FWIW, Clang still doesn't compile it. I can't say for sure whether that's a bug.

Comment: You are right, that was the problem. I suspect it was related to the spaceship generation, but it was simple type deduction.

Comment: Fascinating.. thx for posting that godbolt link !